# What is the difference between C and lambda in the context of an SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I don't understand the difference between the parameter $C$ and $\lambda$ in terms of the [SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine). It seems to me that they are both involved in regulating over-fitting of the data.

What difference between $C$ and $\lambda$?

Answer (score 3):

You are right to be confused. What's going on is that the hyperparameters refer to different formulations. On the one hand there is a generic empirical risk minimizer

$$\lambda\lVert \mathbf w \rVert^2 + \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \max\left(0, 1 - y_i(\mathbf x_i^T \mathbf w + w_0)\right)$$

On the other there is the soft-margin objective

$$\frac{1}{2} \lVert \mathbf w \rVert^2 + C \sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i$$

such that $$\xi_i \geq 0, y_i\left(\mathbf x_i^T \mathbf w + w_0\right) \geq 1-\xi_i, \forall i$$

The first one places SVM in the framework of empirical risk minimization, in which the objective is an expected loss plus the $L_p$-norm of the main parameter. The purpose of introducing *slack* variables and constraints in the second formulation is to allow a fraction of points (adjustable by $C$) to lie on the wrong side of the margin, and eliminate the non-differentiable $\max$ function. Moreover, it draws attention to the fact that SVMs encode sparsity in the loss function, rather than the prior. This is called the *primal* form and can be solved using quadratic programming. Wikipedia currently explains this in the [Computing the classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Support_vector_machine&oldid=796006866#Computing_the_SVM_classifier) section. You should be able to see that $C=1/{2n\lambda}$. Some texts omit the $1/2$ or the $n$.