# Difference between C and lambda in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I've been taking the coursera machine learning course and The instructor said that if ( C = 1/lambda )  then the learning algorithm would reach the same optimal value of theta

does this mean that using C instead of lambda is just a convention when using SVM or is there an actual difference ?

P.S 
Please dumb down the answer for me I'm kind of new to this :) Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between C and lambda in the context of an SVM?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22408/what-is-the-difference-between-c-and-lambda-in-the-context-of-an-svm)