# Is C = 1/lambda in SVM?

Tags: classification, svm

I was looking through the documentation for SVM.SVC where it said:

> C: float, default=1.0
> Regularization parameter. The strength of the regularization is inversely proportional to C. Must be strictly positive. The penalty is a squared l2 penalty

Does this mean it's equal to inverse of lambda for our penalty function? ( Which is l2 in this case )
If so, why cant we directly alter the lambda instead of the inverse of it since that's the hyperparameter in the formula?

Comment: Here is the answer that was previously answered. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/22410/87185